# load mysql data into jquery mobile panel based on selected listview

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a webapp with parent contact data based on a student selected in a listview. I have messed around with the PHP/MySQL stuff a short week now, and I can get it to generate a listview via a while-loop.

The idea is that when I click or touch a listview item, a jQuery panel will slide in and show the corresponding contact information of the parent to that particular student. I have a feeling that a query such as

```
SELECT f_name_mother, f_name_father, m_number (etc...) WHERE id...
```

...is the same as for the student in the chosen listview item. Can someone can point me to a tutorial or example of this?